# Line-wrapping at the SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, actionmailer, sendgrid

I am sending html email and the SMTP server handling emails messages with hard-wrapping at proper length.
I am using sendgrid and rails 3.2.11, need to do soft-wrapping in all lines of message below 1000 character. But I don't know how to do this!.
How can we do soft-wrapping?

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you having trouble wrapping the header lines or the actual email body?

Comment: @Swift thanks for your response. I want to do it for actual email body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ActionMailer `format_paragraph` helper to do soft-wrapping on your paragraphs.  You can find the docs here:

> http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionMailer/MailHelper:format_paragraph

Sample usage would be something like:

*app/views/signup_mailer.html.erb*

```
<%= format_paragraph("Some really really really really long text ...", 1000, 0) %>
```